# Missing libtiff4 while installing Canon MX410 driver on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: printing, canon

I'm really excited  about uing Ubuntu as my main OK. But I still have a couple of things to resolve before I can do that. The first one is to be able to connect to my Canon MX410 printer.  I have found the installation drivers but there was a few dependencies that failed.  So far I was able to find them all but one:  libtiff4

I found several things on the net explaining how to install them but they all failed.  The one that I think I should be using is:

sudo apt install libtiff4

But it cannot find that library.

I installed libtiff5 but the installation driver is still expecting the libtiff4.

I also tried;

sudo apt-get install libtiff4

that failed to find the library.

also tried the libtiff4-dev without success.

I've been on this case for several days now so I can't really tell you everything I tried but my guess is that I tried them all. This is why I'm here now.

Anyboday know what else I should try?

Comment: How about: `sudo apt install libtiff-dev` ? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: `libtiff4` is an Ubuntu 16.04 package. Also available from my backup https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DUKKvui64R5gqVdhxYn-31y8HXmP8lxe?usp=sharing

Comment: @Ichili555 Installing a -dev package fixes a problem in user space. Deary me!

Comment: my libtiff-dev is allready installed and to the latest version (it said). But still the installation is waiting for libtiff4

Comment: @KnudLarsen thank you very much.  That worked finally.  Not sure how to go to record this answer being the right one ;-)

Answer (score 1):

That did it.  Thank you Knud Larsen for the link to the libtiff4.  After installing that library, I was finally able to print.